Disallowing access to specific file(s) on a per-process basis?
Unix has several ways to control file access on a per-user basis. I'm interested to know if there's a way to do this on a per-process basis; in particular making the file unreadable or even invisible for the running process itself.
Is there any mechanism to achieve this?
Example application: a procedure to check which binaries link against a specific shared library without disrupting any functionality during the scan.
